# Frequency modulation synthesis with IQ

Tags: modulation, quadrature

I am trying to figure out how the I & Q signals for a frequency modulation have to look like. How do I generate a FM modulated signal with an IQ mixer?

Comment: Fequency modulation won't come from the mixer

Comment: Do you understand what the I & Q signals are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequency is the rate of change of phase. Take your modulated frequency signal, and time-integrate it to phase.

Now you drive your IQ mixer with I=cos(phase), Q=sin(phase)

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I was totally confused before...